# Does saying that a product is closed make sense?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I have seen statements such as "the set of integers is closed under multiplication", and heard it described as meaning that when any two integers are multiplied, the product will also be an integer.

In this context, would it make sense to say something like, "Multiply the integers 2 and 3.  The product is closed because it is 6, which is also an integer."?

Comment: No, it wouldn't make sense. What is closed (under the operation of multiplication) is the set of integers.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  That's what I thought, but confirmation is good to have.  Is there a definitive reference for this you'd be able to point me to?

Comment: Don't know whether it is a definitive reference, but there is https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(mathematics).